# how do i deal with c# left-hand side

Tags: c#

i wanna ask something. My script gots some error

Here is it

```
using System;

namespace 3nplus1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            int n  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            
            while (Convert.ToBoolean(n = 1))
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(n % 2  = 0))
                   {
                    n = n / 2;
                    Console.WriteLine(n);
                }
                else
                {
                    n = 3*n + 1;
                    Console.WriteLine(n);
                }
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
}
```

The error message says:"/Error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer (CS0131) (3nplus1)

The error is located on the first "if" line
Please help.
Thanks and sorry for bad English.

Comment: 'Convert.ToBoolean(n = 1)' incorrect... use equal operator `==` and better without `Convert`. Simply `n == 1`

Comment: `=` is an assignment. You probably want to use the equals operator `==`

Answer (score 1):

change this part of your code

```cs
while (n != 1)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n = n / 2;
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
    else
    {
        n = 3*n + 1;
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }   
}
```

A single `=` represents an assignment, however in your case you want to check for equality and therefore use the `==` operator. Doing this eliminates the need to use `Convert.ToBoolean`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the `=` operator(assignment) with the `==` operator which is used for comparisons. So this is not a comparison that evaluates to true but an assignment(that returns the value that you assign).

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(n % 2  = 0))
```

but the compiler complains about it because there must not be an expression on the left side of the assignment(like here) but a variable. You also don't need those `Convert.ToBoolean`.

Well, as said this is just a followup error. You want something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number(exit with q): ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
while (!input.Equals("q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    int n;
    while (!int.TryParse(input, out n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid integer");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    int result = n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : 3 * n + 1;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With an `=` you assign a value to a variable or a property. But you want to make a comparison on the equality and for that you take two `==`.

And by the way you don't need `Convert.ToBoolean`. Just write:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    ...
}
```